# Passing variable-length 2D array to functions using template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, multidimensional-array

Here is an example of the problem I am having:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t U, std::size_t V>
void func2(int (&twoDArrayA)[U][V], const int shift){
    const int length = 1 << shift;
    int twoDArrayB[length][length]; //Successful
}

//template<std::size_t A> <-- Tried to solve the problem by adding this
void func1(const int shift){
    const int length = 1 << shift;
    int twoDArrayA[length][length]; //Failed

    func2(twoDArrayA,shift);
}

int main() {
    const int shift = 3;
    func1(shift);
}
```

Error message:

> error: no matching function for call to 'func2(int [length][length], const int&)'
> template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> variable-sized array type 'int' is not a valid template argument

I thought it is because of the use of the template before the **func2**, so I tried to do the same thing on **func1**. The attempt of making the call to **func1** fails instead. Error message:

> error: no matching function for call to 'func1(const int&)'
> template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> couldn't deduce template parameter 'A'

Is there any way I can pass such an argument as **twoDArrayA** to func2?

Comment: What about simply using `std::vector<T>` in preference of rolling your own stuff?

Comment: Regarding _"`int twoDArrayA[length][length]; //Failed`"_ - You may find this Interesting : [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: That does not make your array a variable-length array though. That's still fixed-length because the compiler evaluates those two template parameters at compile-time. The template method can not be an alternative to `std::vector` in every case.

Answer (score 0):

`func2` is failing to deduce the array size because it isn't known at compile time; `length` is being decided at runtime based on the argument you pass to `func1`. For the pass-by-reference to work with template arguments and deduction, you will need to have a 2D array with defined size at compile time, for example, `int arr[8][8]`.

It looks like the code you're working on wants to decide the array size in `func1` based on `shift` and then pass that array to `func2`. You might consider designing `func2` to take an `int**` and then access it as you would a 2D array, based on the result of `1<<shift`:

```
void func2(int** twoDArrayA, const int shift) {
  const int length = 1 << shift;
  int last_item = twoDArrayA[length-1][length-1]
}
```

You might also find some more helpful resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)!

Comment: I wonder how should I define twoDArrayA in this case.